# error 1069 the service did not start due to a logon failure while starting sqlserver service

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have found the answer of this issue;
the answer is to right click on the service / properties and logon tab then you should change the password;
but when I change the password and click apply my password does not work and it changes automatically to old one;

what you think I can do now?

Answer (score 0):

This is the wrong forum to ask this question, but your issue is either you're putting in the wrong password for the service account.

**OR**

The user account you are using with the service does not have correct SQL permissions.

You should read up on SQL Permissions:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669084(v=vs.110).aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669065(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you tried to update the password the SQL service uses via Windows Services, try instead via SQL Server Configuration Manager. Doing it via Windows Services will not work correctly.

And if you are not 100% sure you are typing the correct password, you may need to update the logon account's password first.